# What inserts space inside empty curly braces block?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-formatting

- Using Visual Studio 2015, editing `C#` code, typing two character sequence `{}`.
- 'Something' constantly inserts single space inside the block resulting in `{ }`, which might be pretty annoying for someone.

**What is causing this behavior when all IntelliSense and Resharper formatting is disabled?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not very intuitive and expected:

`Smart` choice in Visual Studio menu item `Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Tabs/Indenting` is causing this behavior. Changing it to `Block` stops it...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Resharper then go to Resharper->TemplateExplorer then you can edit however you want

[image]