# Turn off visual studio's whitespace formatting with braces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I manually close braces due to other IDEs I use which don't have brace completion. Visual Studio does have brace completion though -- it doesn't add a second closing brace when I manually close, but since I'm manually closing braces as soon as I write the opening one, I'm creating empty braces constantly. By default, Visual Studio puts a space between empty braces, so when I do something such as: type `char a[] = {}`, left arrow, type `'a','b','c'`, the result is

`char[] a = { 'a','b','c'}`

instead of

`char[] a = {'a','b','c'}`

I'm on a constant basis having to fight Visual Studio's whitespace autocompletion. Further, when I create a nested array, it inserts spaces between the brace pairs as well, i.e. `blah = {{}}` becomes `blah = { { } }`

I don't want to disable autoformatting completely, as there are some features I find useful such as auto-spacing between function/class names and their opening braces. With that in mind, how can I get Visual Studio to stop doing these two things? I've checked in options for spacing, but it appears there are only options for square brackets. [These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEdgy.png) are my settings for spacing, if it helps.

Comment: what Visual Studio?

Comment: @KeithNicholas Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: well, all the toys are under Tools -> Options ->C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> Spacing

Comment: @KeithNicholas I've looked there (and have included a screenshot of my settings in the question), but I haven't been able to find anything that seems to control these particular features. I'm wondering if it might be a setting that's not as obvious like in this [answer to a similar question concerning Resharper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501598/what-inserts-space-inside-empty-curly-braces-block) that unfortunately didn't work with Community 2015.

Comment: also your code,  I think you want to edit for cha[] a =

Comment: Whatever spacing you use, a reformat (Ctrl+K+D) will normalize this (tiny) issue. Your typing isn't the final edition.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  right, when he formats, he wants no spacing

Comment: do you have resharper Drew?

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'm not seeing ReSharper in Help>About Visual Studio>Installed Products. All that's listed concerning C# is Visual C# 2015.

Comment: ok.....  I have it, and it has options for controlling it.

Comment: ReSharper or Visual C# 2015 has options?

Comment: resharper does,  has  options "space between empty braces"  and "within single line initializer braces" ( which is your example case )

Comment: Resharper [seems to be a paid product](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) so unfortunately it's not an option for me at the moment.

Comment: are you a student?

Comment: Yes, but I plan on using Visual Studio for commercial work as well